# devextreame use in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, devextreme

I want to use data grid devextreme in react.
I have tried this code but when i run my project i have this error : jQuery is not defined.
when i try to import jquery i still have the error.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import dxDataGrid from '../../node_modules/devextreme/dist/js/dx.all';

class Grid extends Component {

     constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
        dataSource: employees,
        sorting: {
            mode: "multiple"
        },
        columns: [ 
            { 
                dataField: "Prefix",
                caption: "Title",
                width: 70
            }, {
                dataField: "FirstName",
                sortOrder: "asc"
            }, {
                dataField: "LastName",
                sortOrder: "asc"
            }, "City",
            "State", {
                dataField: "Position",
                width: 130
            }, {
                dataField: "HireDate",
                dataType: "date"
            }
        ]
        }
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Grid  value= "false" text= "Disable Sorting for the Position Column"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Grid;
```

Comment: It looks like you are looking for something like this - https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T360499 There is the sample project in the last comment, that shows how to use DevExtreme widgets and React together.

Comment: But, I should say, it isn't the "true-react-way" just a workaround.

Comment: is there any solution that use dxdatagrid exact? @Sergey

Comment: Unfortunately, I've not seen any examples with the dxDataGrid widget.

Comment: I've just modified the sample from my first comment. And it works :) See this [sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y5fhpr012ntbi3a/ReactJSBindingsInDevExtreme.html?dl=0).

Comment: do you know how can i use it in ES6 syntax? I Import devextreme but i have this error that DevExpress.require is not a function. https://jsfiddle.net/lemanslmi/2sgk2yg9/3/ @Sergey

Comment: Sorry for delay. I've created a simple react app using`create-react-app`. Next, I've installed devextreme through npm. And I've got the error `jQuery is not defined` too (( Anyway, if I have some progress here, I'll update this thread.

Comment: hi @Sergey. have you recive any success?